# ZFS pool disappears after reboot on Debian 8

Tags: linux, debian, zfs, sysvinit

I'm getting started with ZFS and I got the basics down, but I'm having an issue with keeping it running.

Pools are created, mounts are created, I'm able to save data and see disk activity… things are looking good. However, after rebooting `zpool list` reports "no pools available".

I have found several articles about this on CentOS which talk about a startup script for zfs being the fix, but thus far I haven't found one on Debian.

I'm using the Debian backport `zfs-dkms` package, which dependency includes `libzfs2linux`, `libzpool2linux`, `bfs-zed`, and `zfsutils-linux`. I am also running in SysV `init` mode instead of `systemd`.

I've tried recreating the pool with `/dev/disk/by-id` as well as standards `/dev/sdx` devices; I've tried editing `/etc/default/zfs` and setting (not all at once):

```
ZFS_MOUNT='yes'
ZPOOL_IMPORT_ALL_VISIBLE='yes'
ZPOOL_IMPORT_PATH="/dev/disk/by-vdev:/dev/disk/by-id"
ZPOOL_IMPORT_PATH="/dev"
ZFS_INITRD_POST_MODPROBE_SLEEP='5'
```

I see my pool configuration names in `/etc/zfs/zpool.cache`; I can re-import everything fine manually with `zpool import <pool-name>` and all the data is there.

Is this a timing issue on boot? I'm running short on possible ideas and any input would be appreciated.

Comment: do you use dracut or similar way of creating initramfs?  Are you stuck in the dracut console?

Comment: I'm not...  Straight out of the box debian jessie.

I do believe at this point that an init script is missing.  Likely something that is handled by systemd but was not tested under the legacy init script setup.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot or dmesg where it hangs?

Comment: Hello @tukan, I think I'm not explaining myself correctly.  The system doesn't hang or crash... I'm not booting off of ZFS, I am using ZFS as a data drive filesystem.  The system comes up fine but none of the ZFS drives appear or mount.  I have to manually import them into zpool and then they are fine.

Comment: Ah, I finally got it :).  I'll post a possible approach.

Comment: So how does it look like?  Does it work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across a mailing list posting yesterday evening that resolves the mystery here.  It indicates `zfs_autoimport_disable` is now compiled as set to 1/true by default! So it doesn't matter what is configured in `/etc/default/zfs`, the pools will never import when the zfs module loads.

So the fix for me was to add an `/etc/modprobe.d/` config file (call it what you like) and define `options zfs zfs_autoimport_disable=0`.  Now the pools are imported and the zfs file systems can be mounted either by zfs or in legacy mode.

I don't understand this decision, but now everything is working as expected...

Comment: Haha such simple thing.. Accept your solution for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

First backup the `/etc/default/zfs` and then remove it.

I would recommend going for the `legacy` approach.  This will remove the automount zfs feature and rely on `/etc/fstab` for mounting information.  I also recommend using `/dev/disk/by-id` always as it the the least painful setuop.

Since I don't know your setup (pool/datasets), I'll make up an example:

1. First list your dataset you want: `zfs list`
   take the dataset you want e.g. `storagepool/backup`
2. Umount your `storagepool/backup` zfs if mounted. (You can check via `mount | grep zfs` or `zfs mount`)
3. List your mountpoints with `zfs get mountpoint`:

> ```
> NAME                    PROPERTY    VALUE                   SOURCE
> storagepool/backup      mountpoint  /storagepool/backup     default
> ```

3. Change your mountpoint `zfs set mountpoint=legacy storagepool/backup`
4. Now you have to edit `/etc/fstab` via `sudo` or `root` Enter
   second line (first line is there for explaining the details)

> ```
>     <device alias dataset>   <mountpoint>   <filesystem type>  <options> <dump> <fsckorder>
>     storagepool/backup       /mnt/backup     zfs               defaults   0      0
> ```

Detail explanation:

- The *first field* (storagepool/backup) usually physical device/remote
  filesystem which is to be described, in your case pool/dataset (NOTE:
  there is no leading backslash ('/') for zfs dataset!! (caused me many troubles))
- The *second field* (/mnt/backup) specifies the mount point where the
  filesystem will be mounted.
- The *third field* (zfs) is the type of filesystem on the device from
  the first field.
- The *fourth field* (noauto,suid,ro,user) is a (default) list of options
  which mount should use when mounting the filesystem.
- The *fifth field* (0) to decide if a filesystem should be backed up. If
  zero then dump will ignore that filesystem.
- The *sixth field* (0) is used by fsck (the filesystem check utility) to
  determine the order in which filesystems should be checked.

> *default* option means: `rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async`
>   If you are using SSD, which is unlikely, I recommend using `noatime` after `defaults` option.

Now, when you reboot, the zfs filesystem should be mounted according to the `/etc/fstab` file.

**Important Note:** If you want to mount a *zfs legacy* you have to use `mount -t zfs <dataset> <mountpoint>` instead of `zfs mount`.

Comment: Hi Tukan, I do already have the legacy option defined and they are in the fstab, but that hasn't resolved the problem.

Comment: Tukan, also many thanks for your clear and detailed posting of the fstab configuration.  This is very nicely posted and clearly defined.  That will be very helpful.

Comment: I'm glad you like it!

Answer (score 0):

@Peter-B
Your solution solved my problem with zpool failing to import on reboot. Many thanks. 
A small clarification for those unfamiliar with modprobe conf syntax: the option needs to be on a single line, ie.

`options zfs zfs_autoimport_disable=0`

Comment: Welcome to Super User! The site's Q&A format reserves answers for solutions to the question.  This post is really a comment rather than an answer. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but additionally, I used encryption with passwords stored in keylocation. `zfs mount -l -a` resolved my issue. For a more detailed description refer here https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/8750